# Maps API - Disable parts of the map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, bing, bing-maps

I am doing some research for what Map API to use for a coming project.

The main requirement is the ability to lock a map, and the ability to disable parts of the map.

Think about a special purpose map for Europe where I would like to disable and gray out the non-european countries.

A click on those grayed out areas should do nothing, meaning for all of the world except for Europe.

So, is it possible to disable large portions of the map? 
Is it possible to add layers for the borders for each country, that is clickable, for instance on Germany?

I am looking at Bing or Google Maps at this point. Which one is more developer friendly one?

Bing looks so much nicer with the birds eye, much easier to read out the map and know what you are looking at. I find Googles full of clutter and always have problem knowing what I am looking at.

Comment: Your last paragraph, if I understand it correctly, you can change the appearance of the map if you wish.

Comment: Yes, but still, the Google Map i've found less user-friendly though ... I think they tend to highlight things a bit incorrectly, plus you can't rotate a map. If you are walking up the road to take a left, you don't want to look it upside down.

Comment: You are right I guess. I haven't thought about that, as I've never dealt with situations like these. I guess the only reason for you to choose google maps api, is the google maps data.

Answer (score 0):

Possible approach(google-Maps): use a Polygon with multiple paths.

- 1 path for the entire world(vertices defined in clockwise order)
- other paths for the enabled area(vertices defined in opposite clockwise order)

The result will be a polygon that covers the entire world with a hole for the enabled area. The map will not respond to click-events outside the enabled area(because it's covered by the polygon). The map will still respond to dblclick and zoom in, but this may be avoided by cancelling the propagation of the dblclick-event of the polygon.

It wouldn't be possible to gray out the dissabled area, but you could use the fillColor of the polygon to signalize which part of the map is disabled.